# Preserving White Space in qw

Tags: perl

Is there any way to preserve some white space in qw?  For example:

```
my @a=qw(1234 John Smith 123 Main St.);
```

will produce an array containing 6 elements.  Is there any way to, oh I don't know... escape the white space to keep some of it?  Something like:

```
my @a=qw(1234 John\ Smith 123\ Main\ St.);
```

to return 3 elements: '1234', 'John Smith', '123 Main St.'?

(FYI, I've tried the above, also with varying combinations of quotes, all to no avail)

Comment: `qw` => `quote words` and not white spaces. You can `my @a= split /-/, q(1234-John Smith-123-Main St.);`

Comment: why not use simple array? `my @a = ('1234', 'John Smith', '123 Main St.');`

Comment: just change the IFS to something that does not contain "space" ? And change the rest of the script accordingly [when the IFS differs, many treatments on lines will act differently]. You can "restore" the original IFS [you jsut need to save it in another variable, before changing it, and restore from that other variable] as soon as you no longer need it to be different.

Comment: @foibs, This was an oversimplified example.  I would really be using a qw with dozens of entries, separated by newlines, etc.  Doing this repetitively, would mean a lot of typing of quotes, commas, and other punctuation.

Comment: So store it like plain scalar string and split by newlines.

Comment: One suggestion from [this PerlMonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=103970) on the same topic is to use `__DATA__`. If you need multiple data sets, you can use [Inline::Files](http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Inline-Files-0.68/lib/Inline/Files.pm) (which is still experimental, so be careful if you go this route).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To just separate by newlines:

```
my @a = split /\n/, <<'END';
1234
John Smith
123 Main St.
END
```

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot preserve whitespace with `qw`. As mpapec mentions in the comments, `qw` is for quoting *words*. Here are a few alternatives:

### Simple array

```
my @a = ('1234', 'John Smith', '123 Main St.');
```

### Heredoc + split

```
my $string = <<'END';
1234
John Smith
123 Main St.
END

my @a = split /\n/, $string;
```

### __DATA__

```
my @a = <DATA>;
chomp @a;

__DATA__
1234
John Smith
123 Main St.
```

### Multiple __DATA__ areas with [Inline::Files](http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Inline-Files-0.68/lib/Inline/Files.pm)

*Credit goes to dga from [this PerlMonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=103970) on the same topic.*

**Disclaimer:** This module is experimental. Take note of the following warning from the documentation:

> It is possible that this module may overwrite the source code in files that use it. To protect yourself against this possibility, you are strongly advised to use the -backup option described in "Safety first".

Be careful if you go this route.

```
use Inline::Files;

my @a = <FOO>;
chomp @a;

my @b = <BAR>;
chomp @b;

__FOO__
1234
John Smith
123 Main St.

__BAR__
5678
Jane Doe
456 Anonymous Ln.
```

### External flat data files

It's often a bad idea to hard-code data into your scripts, so in general this is the route I would go.

*data.txt*

```
1234
John Smith
123 Main St.
```

*myscript*

```
open my $fh, "<", "data.txt" or die $!;

my @a = <$fh>;
chomp @a;

close $fh;
```

### External CSV

*data.csv*

```
1234,"John Smith","123 Main St."
5678,"Jane Doe","456 Anonymous Ln."
```

*myscript*

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new() or die Text::CSV->error_diag();

open my $fh, "<", "data.csv" or die $!;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { 
    # $row is an arrayref
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();

close $fh;
```

### Relational Database???

Now I'm just being facetious. My point is, there's more than one way to skin this cat.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of such records, read them in from a text file and use `split()` to get the individual elements of the records. If your input text file doesn't have proper column separators then you might be better off fixing the input file somehow (e.g. by modifying the program that produced it in the first place). If you use `__DATA__` you will still need to get the column separators right. I suggest you use tabs as column separators but any character which you are sure does not exist in your data will do.

Comment: IFS is a bash variable with no direct equivalent in Perl (see `$/` and ``$\`` in [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar), though).

Comment: Please don't make comments to other users in answers (that's what comments are for).

Answer (score 1):

There multiple way to do it. My favorite is to choose a specific escape sequence to replace spaces. For example `_`:

```
my @a = qw(A_B C);
y/_/ / for @a;
```

or a more elaborate sequence like `_SPACE_`:

```
my @a = qw(A_SPACE_B C);
s/_SPACE_/ /g for @a;
```