# How can I change the behavior of qw() to newline only?

Tags: perl

my code looks like this:

```
my @street = qw(
examplestreet
example street
);
foreach my $str (@street) {
    print "$str\n";
}
```

the output is obviously

```
examplestreet
example
street
```

but I would like it to be

```
examplestreet
example street
```

**Question:** Can I modify the behavior of `qw()` so, that it only separates by newline, instead of any whitespace?

**Ps:** 
Why I'm doing this: Got plenty of entries, and it's simplest to just copy-paste them line by line into the code. It's just a small snipped, not much worth any effort. If I don't find a solution I will make separate files for the data and read them into the script. But a shortcut would be awesome!
(Or should I try something with `__DATA__` ? Don't know how to achieve this though...) Current Perl is `v5.20.1`

Comment: Related: [Preserving White Space in qw](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20858981/176646)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't change the behaviour of `qw`, but you can use a HERE document instead:

```
my @streets = split /\n/, << '__LINES__';
examplestreet
example street
__LINES__

print "<$_>\n" for @streets;
```

A HERE document is always a single string, so you have to [split](http://p3rl.org/split) it on newlines.

Using DATA might be also possible, but only if there's only one such a section needed (and you don't want to use [Data::Section](http://p3rl.org/Data::Section)):

```
my @streets = <DATA>;
chomp @streets;  # This time, we have to remove the newlines from the strings.
print "<$_>\n" for @streets;

__DATA__
examplestreet
example street
```

Comment: Can you also give an example where the HEREDOC is assigned to a variable? If this is even possible... Otherwise the code logic would be a complete mess, when several times divided by 1000 lines of data.Thanks for your quick answer anyways!

Comment: Can't change the behaviour of `qw`? I beg to [differ](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Syntax::Feature::QwComments)

Comment: @ikegami: Well, **you** can :-)

Comment: @ikegami In response to your comment on my answer (which I deleted since you were right and it added nothing), I was trying to answer the part of the question "how can I make `qw` do something else" with the point that you can't because `qw` doesn't work like that. That was the attempt, it was very poorly done.

Answer (score 3):

You could also read line-by-line from a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $streets = <<EO_STREETS;
examplestreet
example street
EO_STREETS

open my $in, '<', \$streets
    or die "Cannot read from string buffer";

while (my $street = <$in>) {
    $street =~ s/\s+\z//; # just in case
    print "Street: '$street'\n";
}

close $in;
```

This does have the advantage of reducing your script's memory footprint compared to `split`ing a heredoc.